# MQTT Error: Connection refused. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: docker, mqtt, mosquitto, thingsboard

I've set up Docker on Ubuntu because I am experimenting with ThingsBoard, and I'm trying to publish data from a client device using mosquitto broker, but ran into this error.

What am I doing wrong?
This is the command from the terminal on Docker that I used to publish data:

```
mosquitto_pub -h "localhost" -p "1883" -t "v1/devices/me/telemetry" -u "token" -m {"temperature":28}
```

This is how I first ran the docker:

```
docker run -it -p 9090:9090 -p 1883:1883 -p 5683:5683/udp -v ~/.mytb-data:/data -v ~/.mytb-logs:/var/log/thingsboard --name mytb --restart always thingsboard/tb-postgres
```

I usually access the docker only doing:

```
sudo docker start mytb
```

I tried to see what service was listening on port 1883, but nothing showed up

```
lsof -i :1883
```

I found this error with `cat /var/log/thingsboard/thingsboard.log | grep ERROR`

```
2021-02-10 10:45:45,955 [nioEventLoopGroup-4-4] ERROR o.t.s.t.mqtt.MqttTransportHandler - [50256c63-211b-422f-b793-b88212d88977] Unexpected Exception
```

Lines below the error above are:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 103b00064d51497364700382003c00176d6f73717075622f3634382d353434646636323466343500146a4f767a4e4a796b656a426f556845496b436170
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:471)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 103b00064d51497364700382003c00176d6f73717075622f3634382d353434646636323466343500146a4f767a4e4a796b656a426f556845496b436170
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1261)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1329)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
```

Comment: There is quite a lot of information missing. Please provide more detail, for example the command you use to run the container, log files or messages. Sadly no one will be able to help you like that.

Comment: @GutZuFusss I am very sorry. I edited my post

Comment: No need to be sorry! Can you also provide the lines below the error message you have shown? There should be some detail about the exception.

Comment: @GutZuFusss Yes, these are the lines below (I will edit the main post because the comment will be too long)

Comment: This sounds like a MQTT/MQTTS mismatch. Could You check all your settings and do not use SSL anywhere.